# Setting timeout to recv function

Tags: c++, sockets, visual-c++, recv

I read from socket using `recv` function. I have problem when no data available for reading. My programm just stops. I found that I can set timeout using `select` function. But looks that timeout affects select function itself and `recv` that goes after select still waits uncontinuously.

```
fd_set set;
struct timeval timeout;
FD_ZERO(&set); /* clear the set */
FD_SET(s, &set); /* add our file descriptor to the set */
timeout.tv_sec = SOCKET_READ_TIMEOUT_SEC;
timeout.tv_usec = 0;
int rv = select(s, &set, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
if((recv_size = recv(s , rx_tmp , bufSize ,0)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
      {
      ...
      }
```

How to ask `recv` function return after some timout?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should check return value of `select`. `select` will return `0` in case timeout expired, so you should check for error and call `recv` only if `select` returned positive value:

> On success, select() and pselect() return the number of file descriptors contained in the three returned descriptor sets (that is, the total number of bits that are set in readfds, writefds, exceptfds) which may be zero if the timeout expires before anything  interesting  happens.

```
int rv = select(s + 1, &set, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
if (rv == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    // select error...
}
else if (rv == 0)
{
    // timeout, socket does not have anything to read
}
else
{
    // socket has something to read
    recv_size = recv(s, rx_tmp, bufSize, 0);
    if (recv_size == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        // read failed...
    }
    else if (recv_size == 0)
    {
        // peer disconnected...
    }
    else
    {
        // read successful...
    }
}
```

Comment: This code example has an error... the line that reads: `int rv = select(s, &set, NULL, NULL, &timeout);` should read `int rv = select(s+1, &set, NULL, NULL, &timeout);`

Comment: Thank you very much, you're right indeed! `nfds` is the highest-numbered file descriptor + 1.

Answer (score 36):

Another way to set a timeout on `recv()` itself without using `select()` is to use [`setsockopt()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740476.aspx) to set the socket's `SO_RCVTIMEO` option (on platforms that support it).

On Windows, the code would look like this:

```
DWORD timeout = SOCKET_READ_TIMEOUT_SEC * 1000;
setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char*)&timeout, sizeof(timeout));

//...

recv_size = recv(s, rx_tmp, bufSize, 0);
if (recv_size == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    if (WSAGetLastError() != WSAETIMEDOUT)
        //...
}
```

On other platforms, the code would look like this instead:

```
struct timeval timeout;
timeout.tv_sec = SOCKET_READ_TIMEOUT_SEC;
timeout.tv_usec = 0;
setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, &timeout, sizeof(timeout));

//...

recv_size = recv(s, rx_tmp, bufSize, 0);
if (recv_size == -1)
{
    if ((errno != EAGAIN) && (errno != EWOULDBLOCK))
        //...
}
```

Comment: FYI This solution only works on Windows platforms, it can't be used on Unix/Linux/OSX platforms.

Comment: @drbobdugan: Windows is not the only platform that supports `SO_RCVTIMEO`, though on other platforms the input parameter is usually a `timeval` struct instead.  [Linux implements `SO_RCVTIMEO` (and `SO_SNDTIMEO`)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html).  [So does OSX](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/setsockopt.2.html).

Comment: your solution won't work on a Linux/Unix/OSX platform because it contains code fragments like DWORD, WSAGetLastError() which are Windows artifacts.

Comment: On other platforms, use `errno` instead of `WSAGetLastError()`.  As for the Windows-centric nature of my answer, it is because the question is tagged with `visual-c++`, which means Windows-only development.

Comment: I have updated my answer to account for other platforms.

Comment: Awesome thanks @Remy Lebeau now I see have two nice solutions to this stackoverflow questions.

Comment: does not work on ubuntu 16.04 LTS - wait for timeout is NOT happening, -1 is returned immediately

Comment: @serup Ubuntu supports `SO_RCVTIMO`, according to the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man2/getsockopt.2freebsd.html).

Answer (score 1):

use the FD_ISSET() macro to test whether there is data to read. If it returns false, don't do the read.

http://linux.die.net/man/3/fd_set